# How do I recharge an internal 18360 3.7 volt battery for a Cubii Pro Eliptical

Tags: power-supply

I have a Cubii Pro exercise machine that uses a 3.7v internal #18650 battery for the bluetooth feature.The micro USB port broke away from the charging board and the manufacturer cannot supply a spare circuit board or part. (Machine is made in China) I bought a small Reedy 123-S charger on Amazon, but the three soldered wires on the battery has a much smaller female 3 pin connector than the 3 pin male port on the charger. I believe the small connector is a mini-micro JSt 2.0 3pin female connector that is very similar to internal computer board cables. I have researched electronic sites and local electronic repair shops in my area (Delray Beach, Fl. with no luck. Are there any converter cables that will fit the mini 3 pin connector and plug into the Reedy charger? I was told to buy a new Cubii from the manufacture for $300. Nothing is wrong with mine. I am a senior on fixed income. I still have time to send the charger back to Amazon... if there is no way to charge the battery.

Comment: Instead of trying to charge the battery yourself (dangerous, could cause the battery to explode) why not try to replace the connector on the charging board? That seems like it would be much easier.

Comment: Is it a 18650 or 18360 as stated in your title? Also, please provide a picture of the charger and battery.

Comment: It is an 18650 Lipo battery 3.7v 2200mAh with a black, red and blue wires attached in a wrapped blue tape. I sent the charger back and now have a c150 ac/dc HTRC charger from amazon (china) that has multiple connections with alligator clips and various adapters. when I connect just the black and red with the proper voltage and amperage... I get a "disconnect" battery message. Now getting ready to send this charger back.. no help from web site or Chinese phone number/email for tech support